# Minimum path in an undirected graph with locked and unlocked edges

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Given an undirected graph with **positive weights**, there are 2 kinds of edges: locked edges and unlocked edges.  Determination if a given edge is either locked or unlocked edge takes O(1).

1. For given two vertices *s* , *t* and a positive number *k* = O(1), how can I find the shortest path between *s* and *t* which contains **at most** *k* locked edges?
2. For given two vertices *s* , *t* and a positive number *k* = O(1), how can I find the shortest path between *s* and *t* which contains **exactly** *k* locked edges?

I'm not sure how can I run Dijkstra algorithm on this graph to find the shortest path between the given vertices, and how can I transform the **undirected** graph, into an **directed** one.

Comment: Are paths allowed to contain cycles?  Or are these simple paths?

Comment: Treat locks as weight. If it is a locked edge it has a weight of say 1000. That should simplify it.

Comment: (By the way - nice Supaplex icon!) :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can solve both of your problems by taking `k` copies of the graph, say G_0, ..., G_k, and modifying each graph so that a locked edge vw in G_i turns into an edge from u in G_i to v in G_{i+1} and from v in G_i to u in G_{i+1}.  Then you can do single-source shortest paths from your root in G_0.  The second query is solved by reading off the distance to the target in G_k, while the first is solved by reading off the minimum distance in any G_i to the target.

Comment: so if u is connected to v, and v is connected to u, why should I copy the whole graph (or just the vertices?) k times, and transform it into a directed one? and what about the "unlocked" edges? Sorry I haven't totally got your solution...

Comment: I thought to define a counter the initialized to k, and decrease each time I found locked edge during dijkstra algo. Is there any problem with this solution?

Comment: You leave the unlocked edges alone.  That is, an unlocked edge between u and v becomes an edge from u to v and another edge from v to u in G_i for each i.

Comment: The trouble with your proposed solution is that it doesn't work at all if there are any locked edges.  Take a square plus a diagonal edge.  Lock the bottom side of the square and the diagonal and give each edge weight 1.  It's possible to get from the bottom left to the top right without using any locked edges, but your solution won't figure that out.

Comment: OK I think I got it, but can you explain a little bit more about the queries?  I've got k graphs G_0,...,G_k, and run Dijkstra algorithm in order to find the shortest path from u to v, what should i do now?  please note that in the second query, the path from u to v that contains exactly K locked edges might be contains the same locked edge more than 1 time..

Comment: What if you looked at the bottom edge before the diagonal?  (What if it had lower weight or something?)

Comment: Sorry I understood my mistake, but didn't totally got the explanation about the queries a and b on the graph. what should I do after running Dijkstra algorithm in order to find the shortest path from u to v? please note that in the second query, the path from u to v that contains exactly K locked edges might be contains the same locked edge more than 1 time

Comment: tmyklebu can you explain a little bit more about the queries please?